# How to display submenu when a principal menu have a scroll?

Tags: html, css, angular, primeng

I'am struggling with this problem :

I'am using angular 8 and `tieredMenu` from primeng 8.

My issue is when I have a scroll the tieredMenu's submenu is hidden

How to resolve it ?

this is HTML file :

```
<div class="app-scroll-perso">
  <div class="scroll-width-perso">
    <p-tieredMenu [model]="items"></p-tieredMenu>
  </div>
</div>
```

TypeScript File:

```
items: MenuItem[];

ngOnInit() {
    this.items = [
        {
            label: 'File',
            icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-pencil'
        },
        {
            label: 'encouragment',
            icon: 'pi pi-briefcase'
        },
        {
            label: 'primeng',
            icon: 'pi pi-save'
        },
        {
            label: 'contact',
            icon: 'pi pi-cloud-upload'
        },
        {
            label: 'Edit',
            icon: 'pi pi-tags'
        },
        {
            label: 'user',
            icon: 'pi pi-user',
            items: [
                {label: 'Delete', icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-trash'},
                {label: 'Refresh', icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-refresh'},
                {label: 'save', icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-refresh'},
                {label: 'modify', icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-refresh'},
                {label: 'nothing', icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-refresh'}
            ]
        },
        {
            label: 'blog',
            icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-pencil'
        }
    ];
}
```

css to apply scroll :

```
.scroll-width-perso {
  max-height: 20vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  width: 180px;
}
```

Below you can find an example of what I've done so far :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3kxful

Comment: Maybe either of these can help: https://css-tricks.com/popping-hidden-overflow/, https://front-back.com/how-to-make-absolute-positioned-elements-overlap-their-overflow-hidden-parent/

Comment: I modified my code I have a same problem https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3kxful?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css

Answer (score 0):

try Specify overflow:visible in css

```
.scroll-width-perso {
max-height: 0vh;
overflow-y: visible;
overflow-x: visible;
width: 180px;
}
```

Comment: my menu have a height fixed, I used to scroll. And if I use overflow: visible; a scroll will be hidden